# XAMPP (7.1.11) is not accessible remotely

Tags: xampp

I plan to open up XAMPP and access with mobile devices. I have adjusted the config `httpd.conf` so that it listens to the IP and `localhost` and `Require all granted`.

Moreover, I disabled my antivirus/firewall. When I browse the pages on the computer (host), the webpage is visible via IP and `localhost`. Unfortunately, a remote computer can never establish a connection (no answer at all) even though the machine is pingable and a tracert unveils all steps.

The command `netstat -ano` shows the computer listening to port 80.

Do you have an idea was can cause the issue?

Comment: Sounds more like a network routing issue. Please add your network topology to the question.

Comment: There are 3 devices: Comp1, Comp2, tablet. I can access from Comp1 to Comp2 but not vice versa. Tablet to Comp2 works as well.

Comment: That suggests a package firewall on Comp1.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have private ip. Try portforwarding your system ip to wan. If you have a issue in that than there is easy option. use NGROK https://ngrok.com/
download and extract and run it and type for windows

```
ngrok http 80
```

after that you will get this message on cmd

```
Session Status                online
Session Expires               7 hours, 59 minutes
Version                       2.2.8
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://06abaef8.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
Forwarding                    https://06abaef8.ngrok.io -> localhost:80

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Use forwarding url now you can access your site from outside.